# How to convert all images to text in a Word document?

Tags: webapp-rec, ocr

These images have text in them and I can't find a tool that does this easily, preferably without any installations.

Answer (score 4):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) can do that.

> When you upload an image file or a scanned PDF to Google Docs, check the option that says “Convert text to Google Docs format” and Google Docs will automatically perform OCR on the file before saving it to your account.
>
> If the OCR operation is successful, all the extracted text is stored as a new document else Google Docs will store your original image without any modification.

You can then export as a Word doc.